# ResourcesNotFoundException only on some screen resolutions in the Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-resources, android-screen-support, android-virtual-device

I used AVD to create a virtual device that is 7 inches and has a screen resolution of 2880x1800. My goal is to get 7-inch screenshots that are high resolution. But my app fails to load on this device. The log says that the resource at `setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout)` is not found. How is that true? It works on every other device from normal to xlarge. Any ideas?

Here's my stack trace.

```
04-21 21:31:52.513    2380-2380/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nsouthproductions.mathanimalsaddition, PID: 2380
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nsouthproductions.mathanimalsaddition/com.nsouthproductions.mathanimalsaddition.Main}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040008
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040008
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2598)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1049)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:870)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.nsouthproductions.mathanimalsaddition.Main.onCreate(Main.java:333)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-21 21:31:52.740      933-933/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 933: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

**EDIT:** adding Java and XML, though they are very standard and are proven to work on other devices.

Java: (error occurs at `setContentView()`)

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Ensures they resume where left off if hit launcher and game already playing
        // If the launcher is trying to create a new instance of Main, this checks to see
        //   if this is a new instance of the app. If not, close this activity so that the
        //   one below it (where they left off) is at the top.
        if (!isTaskRoot()
                && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
                && getIntent().getAction() != null
                && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            START_IN_PLAY = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_SHOWING_PLAY, false);
            START_IN_PRACTICE = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_SHOWING_PRACTICE, false);
            START_IN_QUIZ = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_SHOWING_QUIZ, false);
        }

        context = this;

        mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // call before setContentView to avoid system bars briefly showing
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        System.out.println("checking os version");
        if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            System.out.println("KitKat or newer");
            mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            );
        } else{
            System.out.println("Older than KitKat");
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

`main_layout` for `land` resource

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".Main"
    android:id="@+id/area_main_layout">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:src="@drawable/title_math_animals"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:src="@drawable/title_addition"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/linlay_main_2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_play"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_play"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_play_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_play"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_practice"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_menu_other"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_practice_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_practice"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_quiz"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_menu_other"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_quiz_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_quiz"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_animals"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_menu_other"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_animals_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_animals"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

</LinearLayout>
```

`main_layout` for `land` resource

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".Main"
    android:id="@+id/area_main_layout">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:src="@drawable/title_math_animals"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:src="@drawable/title_addition"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/linlay_main_2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_play"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_play"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_play_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_play"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_practice"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_menu_other"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_practice_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_practice"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_quiz"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_menu_other"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_quiz_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_quiz"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_animals"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_menu_other"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_animals_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_animals"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

</LinearLayout>
```

`main_layout` for `large_land` resource

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".Main"
    android:id="@+id/area_main_layout">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:src="@drawable/title_math_animals"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:src="@drawable/title_addition"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:id="@+id/linlay_main_2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_play"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_play"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_play_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_play"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_practice"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_menu_other"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_practice_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_practice"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_quiz"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_menu_other"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_quiz_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_quiz"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_animals"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_menu_other"  />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_animals_text"
                android:src="@drawable/text_animals"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

</LinearLayout>
```

I cannot post for `xlarge-land` without going over the character limit. I've seen all of these resources load successfully on other devices.

Comment: post your xml and java code.

Comment: Do you have `my_activity_layout.xml` in the root `res/values` directory

Comment: @kcoppock, No I do not. I have it in `res/layout` (and variations thereof).

Comment: @dora, I've updated with my xml and java code, but I know my resources work on other devices and, even if a desired resource is not found, I would expect Android to choose the next best resource available.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `res/layout` :) So you do have one in the default? Not one of the variants -- just `res/layout/my_activity_layout.xml`? Does `my_activity_layout` *include* another layout that does not exist in `res/layout`?

Comment: @kcoppock, That's a good question. I include a number of layouts and not all of them have a simple `res/layout` resource. Do you think that could be part of the problem? For example, one of my includes has normal-land, normal-port, large-land, large-port, xlarge-land, and xlarge-port. Is that not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any resource, you always have to provide a default version (in an unqualified resource directory) as the fallback for when the system cannot determine the most appropriate resource (or there isn't one that matches the current configuration).

See [Providing Resources - Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility) for more info:

> Likewise, if you provide different layout resources based on the
>   screen orientation, you should pick one orientation as your default.
>   For example, instead of providing layout resources in layout-land/ for
>   landscape and layout-port/ for portrait, leave one as the default,
>   such as layout/ for landscape and layout-port/ for portrait.

Comment: Thanks! I ensured every layout resource had a default and now the app doesn't crash. Unfortunately, my Frankenstein device renders very strangely--everything is zoomed in and low res, even the stock home screen. But that may be a bug or an error in setting up the device. Thanks for teaching me something valuable :)